# Reordering a linked list efficiently

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I got this question in an interview which is as followS:

IF I have a linked list like this,

1->2->3->4->5->6

I have to convert it to,

1->6->2->5->3->4

And if it is, like this,

1->2->3->4->5->6->7

I have to convert it to

1->7->2->6->3->5->4

And, most importantly, I have to modify the original linked list and I cannot make a new linked list. I thought of a recursion for this. But, I couldn't really solve it. Moreover, their was a constraint that the function for this can only have the head of the linked list.

Comment: @John Lui Sometimes iterative solution is more simpler.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in linear time `O(n)` and usually during interviews that (unfortunately) counts more than the robustness of the solution.

You can do it by splitting the original list into two (as) equally sized (as possible) list, then reversing the second one and merging both of them element by element (first element from first list, second element from second list etc). You don't need much additional space as you can just use the existing pointers.

For example:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6

1->2->3 and 4->5->6 // after split, 3 points to null, 4 is head of second list
1->2->3 and 4<-5<-6 // after reorder
1->6->2->3 and 4<-5 // first phase of merge
1->6->2->5->3 and 4 // second phase of merge
1->6->2->5->3->4    // last phase of merge
```

You can find the split point using a `running pointer`. You traverse the list with one pointer going one node at a time and one going two nodes at a time. When the faster pointer hits the end (null) the slower pointer will be before the split, the node before the split then has to point to null instead of the next node (in our case instead of 4) and the next node (4) becomes the head of the second list.

Reversing the second list and merging is simple pointer swapping.

Just watch out for null pointers :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a recursive algorithm. You need to traverse the list in a 'spiral' manner (first-last-first-last). So, my idea is to detach the first and last element of the list, connect them and recursively do the same thing on the rest of the elements.

Here's a rough outline of the algorithm:

```
modifyList(head):
    if head.next == null or head.next.next == null: # when the list contains 1 or 2 elements, keep it unchanged
        return head

    nextHead = head.next # head of the list after removing head and last item
    last = head.next
    beforeLast = head
    while last.next != null: # find the last item, and the item before it
        beforeLast = last
        last = last.next

    head.next = last # append last item after first
    beforeLast.next = null # remove the last item from list
    last.next = modifyList(nextHead) # recursively modify the 'middle' elements and append to the previous last item
    return head
```

Comment: it's worth considering this is in n^2 time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive way to do it.

Create a function `nreverse` that reverses a linked list in place. Common Lisp has this function.

Staring at the head of the list, if the list is longer than one element, `nreverse` the list after the first element. In Scheme:

```
(setcdr listx (nreverse (cdr listx)))
```

Recurse on the next sublist of the list. Here's the whole thing in Common Lisp:

```
? (defun munge (listx)
  (let ((balx (cdr listx)))
    (if (null balx)
        listx
        (progn (rplacd listx (nreverse balx))
               (munge (cdr listx))
               listx))))
MUNGE
? (munge '(1 2 3))
(1 3 2)
? (munge '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(1 6 2 5 3 4)
? (munge '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
(1 7 2 6 3 5 4)
?
```